# Tableau question: stuck with tableau equation

Tags: function, powerbi, field, tableau-api

I need to create a calculated field that does the similar as the following

If The month is march, i need the interest rate of February per type

For example

The interest rates for potatoes in February is 2%

And the interest rates for potatoes in march is 3%

I need the interest rates of the previous current month which is 2% as a calculated field

Comment: what's your data source, data structure, and can you edit this outside of Tableau?

Comment: What is the level of detail of your data? For each type,  Do you have one data row per month or several?, say one per day? There are several relatively easy solutions but the right choice depends on that question. The size of the data set can also affect the choice of approach. Different Approaches include: table calcs, self-joins, self-relationships, data blends, SQL windowing queries